# selector datebox with jquery easyui

Tags: tabs, datebox, jquery-easyui

I used Tabs and datebox in easyui. And I have 2 tabs:  tabs1 and tab2

All tabs contain datebox.  I can not selector datebox at tabs2.

$('#dd').datebox is working at tab1 but not work at tab2.

How to selector datebox at tab2 ????

Comment: are you applying the selector on basis of id or css-class?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using id:

```
$('#tab1').datebox();
$('#tab2').datebox();
```

If you are using a same css-class for both tabs:

```
$('.classname').datebox();
```

Hope it helps.
Don't forget to upvote it if it solves you problem.
Thanks.. :)